# How can I use Tika to get just main content with html tags

Tags: apache-tika

Is is possible to somehow use together options--text-main and --html of Tika to get HTML main content of the page?

Comment: Can you not just use BodyContentHandler + a HTML capturing child ContentHandler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the command line `tika-app.jar` file, you need to write a bit of Java code to do it

As shown in [one of the Apache Tika examples](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/ContentHandlerExample.java), your code would need to be something like:

```
ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(
            new ToXMLContentHandler());
String bodyHtml = null;

InputStream stream = ContentHandlerExample.class.getResourceAsStream("test.doc");
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
try {
    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
    bodyHtml = handler.toString();
} finally {
    stream.close();
}
System.out.println(bodyHtml);
```

The output of running that against a Word document with a single paragraph containing "test" is simply:

```
<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">test</p>
```